keycloak 25.0.0 gitlab 301 moved permanently
I recently upgrade to keycloak 25.0.0 image and as a result my gitlab auth doesn't work anymore (it was working fine with 24.0.2)
Maybe some conf changed and I don't understand .
The issue :
enter image description here
My gitlab rb conf :
enter image description here

Please include the config text inline as part of the question body.
